# Using pipe in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, pipe

I'm trying to compile my code in Eclipse

But it wouldnt compile my pipe use.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/wait.h>



using namespace std;
int OpenPipeRead(string sinterface)
{
int ret_val,errno;
string lpipename="",lpipepath="";
lpipepath = mconfig[C_PIPEPATH];
lpipename.append(lpipepath);                    //Its not empty only when there is argument for parallal telepath_sniff instances.
lpipename.append(mconfig[C_PIPENAME]);
if(strcmp(sinterface.c_str(), "") != 0)
    lpipename.append("_" + sinterface);             
printf("Trying to open Pipe for reading\n");
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Try to open Pipe for reading\n"); 
/* Create the named - pipe */
ret_val = mkfifo(lpipename.c_str(), 0666);
if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
    perror("Error creating the named pipe");
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error creating the named pipe");           
    exit(1);
}       
if((pipehandler = open(lpipename.c_str(), O_RDWR)) < 1)     /* Open the pipe for reading and writing , in append mode */
{
    perror("Failed to open pipe file");
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to open pipe file");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Pipe opened.\n");
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Pipe opened.\n");
```

}

```
int main(){
    OpenPipeRead("arg");

}
```

errors are :

../src/main.cpp:325: error: ‘EEXIST’ was not declared in this scope
../src/main.cpp:330: error: ‘O_RDWR’ was not declared in this scope
../src/main.cpp:330: error: ‘open’ was not declared in this scope

It does compile outside of Eclipse

Any includes or flags I need to compile with on Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse is probably using a *different* compiler to compile your code.

Comment: What does it mean about the pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EEXIST MACRO is defined in asm-generic/errno-base.h and the O_RDWR Flag is defined in fcntl.h.

Add :

```
#include <asm-generic/errno-base.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

To the file containing OpenPipeRead definition and it should compile.